# $\exists S \subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be represented as a unique linear combination of numbers with rational coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove $\exists$ infinite set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ can be represented as a unique linear combination of numbers in $S$ with rational coefficients.

I'm not asking if every vector space has a basis.  I already have that proven in my notes so this is NOT a duplicate.

I have that $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis and therefore by definition of a basis, $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented as a linear combination of some vectors $x_i \in B_i$ multiplied by coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't have that this representation is unique.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every vector space has a basis, we can let $S$ be a [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) of $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Then every real $x$ can be represented as a unique linear combination of elements of $S$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to show that that exists though. I don't know how

Comment: This has been proved at this site. It follows from the axiom of choice

Comment: You mean "Every vector space has a vector space basis"?

Comment: Yes, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225341/every-vector-space-has-a-basis).

Comment: That question is similar, but it still doesn't give uniqueness?

Comment: I have that $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis and therefore by definition of a basis, $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented as a linear combination of some vectors $x_i \in B_i$ multiplied by coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't have that this repesentation is unique

Comment: You have that it is unique, because it is a basis!